# Is there any performance downsides to using the `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` JVM flag?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

From what I've read online, it sounds like a lot of people recommend setting the `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` JVM flag to fix high GC pause latencies due to IO blocking when the garbage collector tries to write to `/tmp` (hsperfdata).

I'm trying to optimize the performance of our system's garbage collection, and I tried running a load test before setting the `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` flag and after, and it actually performed slightly better ***without*** the flag!  I even reran the load tests a second time and got the same results.

**So my question is:** Was this just a fluke, or does `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` actually have any potentially negative performance impacts?

(I understand that using `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` will mean that certain diagnostics tools like `jstat` that depend on this file won't work, but we don't use any of those tools -- I'm just asking about potential *performance* downsides, not tooling downsides.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HotSpot JVM maintains certain [Performance Counters](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/docs/Serviceability.html#bjvmstat) that can be read by various serviceability tools.

By default, these performance counters are exported onto the file system under `/tmp/hsperfdata_<user>` directory, so that external tools like `jstat` can read them without direct communication to the JVM. `jps` tool also looks for these counters to find active JVMs.

JVM does not update the file directly; instead it maps the file into memory and updates the counters in memory. Any such memory update can potentialy cause file I/O. For example, when GC counters are updated during a GC pause, the operating system may decide to flush data to disk, and this in turn may extend the pause. [This blog post](https://www.evanjones.ca/jvm-mmap-pause.html) describes the mentioned effect.

`-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` option forces JVM to use anonymous memory for Performance Counters instead of a mapped file. This helps to avoid random VM pauses caused by spontaneous disk I/O.

With this option, `jps`, `jstat`, `JConsole` and other tools won't be able to find the JVM. However, performance counters will be still collected. [hsperf](https://github.com/apangin/hsperf) tool will be able to print these counters anyway.

There is no other negative performance impact of `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` option. JVM updates counters exactly the same way in both cases; the only difference is whether the counters memory is mapped to a file or not.

Comment: You can find some more recent benchmarks covering different GCs and JDK versions for the initial reproducer here https://github.com/simonis/mmap-pause

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to get the performance counters out of a JVM which was started with `-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem` with standard JDK tools. The proposed `jcmd <pid> PerfCounter.print` results in `sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitorException: <pid> not found` caused by `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not map vmid to user Name`. I think the only way to get the counters in such a case is to use `-XX:+PerfDataSaveToFile`/`-XX:PerfDataSaveFile=<file>` but this will only dump the counters to `<file>` at JVM exit.

Comment: @VolkerSimonis Thank you for the correction. I updated the answer to refer to hsperf tool instead.